# My image is appearing and disppearing when i try and move it

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm making a game with JavaScript, HTML, and CSS. The game will be displayed on an HTML5 Canvas. When the arrow keys are pressed the player moves. The problem is when the player is moving the image appears and disappears because I'm using ctx.clearRect(). Is there a way to move the image without using ctx.clearRect()?

This is my script.js file:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("game");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var playerImg = new Image();
var player = {
    x: 200,
    y: 375,
    width: 50,
    height: 50
}

function draw() {
    playerImg.onload = function () {
        ctx.drawImage(playerImg, player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);'
    }
    playerImg.src = "images/player.png";
}

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 37) {
        ctx.clearRect(player.x, player.y, player.x + player.width, player.y + player.height);
        player.x -= 15;
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
        ctx.clearRect(player.x, player.y, player.x + player.width, player.y + player.height);
        player.x += 15;
    }
}, false);

setInterval(draw);
```

Comment: You're defning the src of the image and adding the same onload listener to `playerImg` several times per second. Pull those out of `draw` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was flashing because you cleared canvas and the page is refreshed and nothing is on the screen. The draw timer then fires and it redraw the image again. As Teemu pointed out, although the image would be in cached, assuming it was enabled by the user, it is best not to reload it each time you draw it.

It is best to compare your code with the one below and I've added a couple of comments toward the bottom. Also there is a single quote ctx.drawImage() line that should not be there.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("game");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var playerImg = new Image();
var player = {
    x: 200,
    y: 375,
    width: 50,
    height: 50
}

playerImg.src = "images/player.png";

playerImg.onload = function () {
    draw();
}

function draw() {
        ctx.drawImage(playerImg, player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height);
}

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 37) {
        ctx.clearRect(player.x, player.y, player.x + player.width, player.y + player.height);
        player.x -= 15;
    }
    else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
        ctx.clearRect(player.x, player.y, player.x + player.width, player.y + player.height);
        player.x += 15;
    }
    
    draw(); // Added this line to prevent flashing
    
}, false);

//setInterval(draw); // removed this line
```

Comment: This looks like it would work, but I found 1 problem in this code. The line `playerImg.src = "images/player.png";` should be after you set the line `playerImg.onload = function () { draw(); }`. So I'm going to try changing that and see if it works. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure as I'm quite new to this place, but have you checked all of your curly brackets, full stops and etc.?
Did a error message come up, like a logical error pop up? If so try to use a debugging tool while you start your game, this way when the game crashes (due to the image disappearing) your able to use the debugging tool to find where the problem is within the code. I used the debugging tool when something similar happened to my program. (Was building a scientific calculator using C# and it did the trick for me).